# css property not being set in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

Made simple parrallax but not working..
css top property not being set or access...
How to set TOP to make parallax working.. pz

```
<div class="bg">
<div class="container">
   <h1>Parallax Effect</h1>
   <p class="lead">goes here</p>

</div>
</div>
```

in **CSS**

```
.bg {
background: url('http://sharafmedia.com/images/banner05.jpg') repeat;
background-position: center ;
background-size: cover;
width: 100%;
height: 300px;
top:0;
left:0;
z-index: -1;
padding:10px;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
function parallax(){
   var scrolled = $(window).scrollTop();
   $('.bg').css('top', -(scrolled * 0.3) + 'px');
   console.log($('.bg').css('top', -(scrolled * 0.3) + 'px'));
}

$(window).scroll(function(e){
   parallax();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding **parseInt** to the computed scroll.

```
function parallax(){
   var scrolled = $(window).scrollTop();
   $('.bg').css('top', parseInt(scrolled * 0.3 * -1) + 'px');
   console.log($('.bg').css('top', parseInt(scrolled * 0.3 * -1) + 'px'));
}
```